# AdvertisingId on native libraries

Tags: android, android-ndk, google-advertising-id

Good morning I need to create a dynamic libraries that will be encapsulate in some third part applications and, inside my library, I need to get the advertisingID (provided by Google Play services SDK). In the java layer of my library I have IdentityManager class in which I wrote a function retrieveAdvertisingId that lunches an asyncronous task in order to retrieve the advertise id (I wrote a java test application in which all is working) after that I call a native function in order to pass the results at native level. In the native layer I call the java class constructor of IdentityManager class and invoke the function retrieveAdvertisingId. 
At compile time all is working at runtime I notice a crash:

E  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: **Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient"** on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.test.less.test11-sIf-KgqiKsO88F6PREuBAA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.test.less.test11-sIf-KgqiKsO88F6PREuBAA==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.test.less.test11-sIf-KgqiKsO88F6PREuBAA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]

I follow http://www.androiddocs.com/google/play-services/id.html 
It seems that I have some troubles with Google play services anyone have any idea?